# SSRS - iif expression only matching on first line it reads in results

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I hope someone can help.  I have a dataset that is, for example returning the following rows

```
Region Level    Days

OT     TEAM     121.9675 
OT     TEAM     79.2529 
ME     REGION   68.0013 
OT     REGION   106.1437 
UK     REGION   92.3336 
US     REGION   73.0599 
AP     REGION   75.7024
```

In SSRS I want to see the value where the Level type is Region (so I don't want to include the two Team level values for region OT).  THe expression in the table is

```
=iif(Fields!LEVEL.Value = "REGION", sum(Fields!Days.Value),"fail")
```

I group on the Region, but for OT I am getting 'fail' but in all the others I get the correct amount.  If I change my expression to

```
iif(Fields!LEVEL.Value = "TEAM", sum(Fields!Days.Value),"fail")
```

I get a value for OT (307.36) and 'fails' for the other regions which I would expect but I would not expect to see 307.36 as this is the total for both the TEAM and REGION lines but I am just asking for TEAM.  It's like it matches on TEAM and then gets the totals for OT or before matches on REGION but for OT the first row is TEAM so it fails it.  Hope this makes sense - can anyone help,  I have a similar report working fine, cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Many thanks,

SOME ADDITIONAL EXAMPLES

I have gone into AdventureWorks and created a test table to take a look and still having problems with what I though should be straightforward

Table as follows:

```
Area (nvarchar(50),
Lockup_level (nvarchar(50),
Days (decimal 18,0)
```

Data as follows:

```
OT   REGION   25
OT   TEAM       56
US   REGION   67
US   TEAM       1
UK   TEAM       23
UK   REGION    10
```

I've created a simple SSRS with a table, grouped by Area and then put in the expression as we've discussed (in a number of variations)

```
=iif(Fields!Lockup_level.Value = "REGION", sum(Fields!Days.Value),0)
```

This returns the following to my table:

```
OT   81
UK    0
US   68
```

So it's finding the REGION against OT and US and then summing up the total (including the TEAM line). I can take the sum out and I get the right figures for OT and US but UK is zero - I think because it reads TEAM first...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!LEVEL.Value = "REGION",Fields!Days.Value,0))
```

---

**Update:**

Try converting the value to integer:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!LEVEL.Value = "REGION",
CInt(Fields!Days.Value)
,0))
```

Or use a conditional to determine if the value can be used in the sum.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!LEVEL.Value = "REGION",
IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!Days.Value),Fields!Days.Value,0)
,0))
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Add a tablix with these groups settings:

[image]

Hide the last column and use this expression to calculate the sum:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Level.Value="REGION",Fields!Days.Value,0),"Region")
```

Note the "Region" argument that tells `Sum` function the grouping scope to calculate the sum.

You will se something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Many thanks - I am trying this and I feel I have progressed as it is not giving me the '0' but #error.  I am checking that the Days value is always an integer or number in case this is the problem....

Comment: Many thanks again - I tried those but still not having any luck.  Its related to the Level = "REGION" a bit like it cannot any lines that are "REGION" .  If I limit my resultset to only have the REGION lines its ok, but if I bring the other levels (TEAM, COUNTRY, etc) in and some nulls also in that field, it cannot find anything that Fields!LEVEL.Value = "REGION",...  I cannot work out why.  I will keep looking..

Comment: @L.Harris, share a complete and representative sample of your data

Comment: I've added a further example above - taken it back to basics on Adventure Works!

Comment: Thank you - I am just getting back to it.  Will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The issues you are seeing have to do with the scope of the calculation. For example, if the expression is not in a row with grouping, the `Sum` function will run across the entire dataset because that is the default scope.

A good alternative to avoid confusion is to put this expression at the DataSet level. In your DataSet properties, add a calculated field with your expression. This way, it will be calculated at a row-by-row level as opposed to whatever the scope of the cell in the table happens to be.

Now you can reference the new calculated column in your table as expected.

Comment: Thank you for this.